# Why does the response of AJAX with "_blank" work for first function, but not the second function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a jsp where there are two radio buttons and based on the button clicked I call corresponding function. Both the functions have ajax call and the success response opens the new url in new tab. The first function does it perfectly , but second function doesn't work properly.

Console doesn't show anything. (Chrome)Pop up blocker blocks the response link from second function's ajax response, but not for the first function's ajax response.I don't want the (chrome) browser's pop up blocker to block it. This doesn't happen in Firefox and Safari. I haven't tried against IE yet. But right now happening only in Chrome.

```
function submit(){


    if($('input[name=questionOption]:checked').val() == "A"){   
        yesHelper();                                        
    }else if($('input[name=questionOption]:checked').val() == "B"){
        addHelper();
    }

}

function yesHelper(){
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    var AQuestion = document.getElementById("A_Actual_Question_Id").value;
    var lang= "T";

    var stringifiedInput = JSON.stringify({"A_Actual_Question" : AQuestion, "language" : "T"}); 
    alert(stringifiedInput);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Abcd/efgh/add1",
        type: "POST",           
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: stringifiedInput,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success: function(response){
            window.open("http://localhost:8080/Abcd"+response, '_blank');
        }
    });         
}

function addHelper(){
    var token1 = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header1 = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    var B_Question = document.getElementById("B_ActualQuestion_Id").value;
    var lang1= "T";
    var B1 = document.getElementById("B1_Id").value;


    var stringifiedInput_B = JSON.stringify({"B_Question" : document.getElementById("B_ActualQuestion_Id").value,
    "language" : "T",
    "B1" : B1

    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Abcd/efgh/add2",
        type: "POST",           
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: stringifiedInput_B,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header1, token1);
        },
        success: function(response1){
             window.open("http://localhost:8080/Abcd"+response1, '_blank');

        }
    });         

}
```

Comment: when you execute the second function, does the developer console show any errors? or what happens?  Does it just does nothing?

Comment: Console doesn't show anything. Pop up blocker blocks the response link from second function's ajax response, but not for the first function's ajax response.

Comment: Some browsers prevent `window.open` if it is without user interaction..

Comment: try showing the response using `console.log();` instead of opening a window so we can know more about the issue @user3705478

Comment: @RayonDabre But why and how does it work for the ajax response of first function in same browser, but doesn't work for second function.

Comment: @KhaledAl-Ansari You mean console.log(window.open("http://localhost:8080/Abcd"+response, '_blank');)   or console.log() instead of    window.open("http://localhost:8080/Abcd"+response, '_blank');

Comment: @user3705478, Yes, It works for the first `window.open` but considers later `.open` calls as spam..

Comment: @RayonDabre So how can I overcome it? Any solutions please.

Comment: @user3705478 console.log(response);

Comment: it returns the value of response1 /Abcd/4185294d

Comment: What is the actual use case. What is the user supposed to do and see?

Comment: The user clicks Submit button and based on the radio button chosen by the user, corresponding JS method is called. The JS methods have a ajax call where the response is a url and it has to be opened in a new tab. This works fine for all browsers but in chrome, yesHelper function works but not for addHelper() method. It shows pop up blocked. But in chrome browser also yesHelper works.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want browsers to block a popup, then you must open it directly on some sort of user interaction (such as a click on something) – otherwise, most current browsers *will* block it in default settings, because popups opened *without* user interaction are usually the ones users don’t want (advertising, or other annoying stuff.)

Now, making an asynchronous AJAX request first, and then trying to open the popup in the success handler, has already “decoupled” this from the initial user interaction.

You could instead try to:

- make a synchronous AJAX request instead (not recommendable),
- open the popup first (address `about:blank`), make the AJAX request, and then change the location of the popup window afterwards.

Comment: 1) If most browsers don't allow this behavior, then how it is working for the ajax response in function yesHelper()
2) Could you provide me sample code for synchronous AJAX request and why it is not recommended?
Thanks for answering.

Comment: Might be that the blocker lets it through the first time, but when it happens repeatedly it starts to think there’s something fishy going on … // Maybe (multiple) popups aren’t the best choice for what you are trying to achieve (whatever that actually is?) in the first place.

Comment: @CBore Could you tell me how to do open the popup first (address about:blank), make the AJAX request, and then change the location of the popup window afterwards. ? Any code reference would be helpful.

Comment: Store the return value of the `window.open` call, and then use that to change the location of that window object afterwards … `var foo = window.open('about:blank', …)`, `foo.location.href="…"`

Comment: Could you give the full code if possible. Please. I am a new bie w.r.t front end technology.