# If we can get session from HttpServletRequest as request.getSession(), then why do some methods have HttpSession session as parameters along with req?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring&I came across code [@RequestMapping("/dosomething")  public String requestHandlingMethod(Model model - Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/MUYhDTZs) If we can get session from request as `request.bgetSession()`. then what is the point of having `HttpSession session` as argument? What's need of `HttpSession` class?

Comment: Please use code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think of standard programming: if you needed only the content of the session object, why would you use the whole request object as input parameter for your function? I think it is not useless that Spring Controllers provide this.

Comment: I think that using HttpSession as input enforces the that a session must exist, thus it will not be null. If you only set the request as input you will enforce nothing, so the session may not be set.

Comment: and then, request.getSession() may return null if you didn't initialize the session before

Comment: Could you answer this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403846/why-does-the-response-of-ajax-with-blank-work-for-first-function-but-not-the/35408489?noredirect=1#comment58556793_35408489

Comment: I think the users have given you good answers there. Btw if you are satisfied with this answer, please mark it as right one.